# creating a UDP packet I can split

Tags: .net, vb.net, udp, packet

I'm building a simple udp lan chat application in vb.net and I'm wondering how I should split my packets. Each sent packet should have like an id, a username and ip address from where it's coming and maybe also a command part for like join or leave to update my userlist  and a text message. I'd like to know what is the easiest way to put all this in a simple packet then easily split and access different parts from it when it's received. thanks.

I'm using UDP since this is only in lan so i'm broadcasting to `*.*.*.255`

EDIT: Thank you for your answer Jon but I already know all that. What I want to know is what would be the most easy and powerful way to format my packets so they include a username , an id, a command and a text message, then the user receiving it decrypt it to show only the message written by which user or if it's a command like join or leave to show the appropriate message of joining and add the user to the list for exemple.

Comment: I'm confused as to which bit of formatting you're stuck on. Is it how to cope with "long" messages? If so, you'll need some sort of sequential packet ID - which means implementing something quite like TCP/IP to cope with lost packets etc. If that's not it, please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably just format the packet in xml and then on the receive side use linq to xml to pull it apart.  You could also use JSON for the format but that might be slightly harder to parse.

Answer (score 2):

Create an appropriate class with an instance `ToByteArray` method and a static `FromByteArray()` method (for serializing to a byte array and parsing from a byte array respectively). Then use [`UdpClient.Send()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08h8s12k.aspx) to send it, and [`UdpClient.Receive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive.aspx) to receive it.

You may want to use `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` and/or `BitConverter` to help with the `ToByteArray` and `FromByteArray` methods. You can use a `MemoryStream` as a quick in-memory stream to pass to `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter`.

Comment: Interesting the char* equivelent in C#, is having to create roughly 4-5 more methods - nice.

Comment: @Zenikoder: If you're talking about "serialization" of just dumping memory, getting it right in a portable way is harder than you're making it sound.